# Add Launch Screen Image instead of using LaunchScreens.storyboard for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, launch-screen

I'm doing my UI for my iOS apps programmatically. The only things that is left is the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` where I didn't find a way around using it, yet.
Strangely I can't find much about that in the internet.

Is there a way to get rid of it and use an AssetSet instead?

[image: LaunchScreen.storyboard]

That's (the highlighted file) what I want to get rid of

Comment: I dont think can do that file programatically as it is what is shown as the app is loading. you would normally just add an imageView and an image here that shows whilst the app is booting up. It doesn't allow you to start writing code for this screen as far as I am aware

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to code the LaunchScreen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855526/is-there-any-way-to-code-the-launchscreen-programmatically)

Comment: No, The launchscreen shows before the app starts, it provide the transition while your app is loading. You can put image of your app on launchscreen to show app is launching. The storyboard scence is actually loaded by the OS, so it is security to excute the code.

Comment: It was possible in the times when StoryBoard was relatively new.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the question included *"use a View or and UIImage instead?"*

From Apple's docs...

> **Static Launch Screen Images**
>
> It’s best to use an Xcode storyboard for your launch screen, but you can provide a set of static images if necessary.

Reference page, including a list of required image sizes: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

Note: To use images instead of a storyboard...

In Xcode open your Assets catalog (or create a new one), right-click in the assets section and select `App Icons & Launch Images -> New iOS Launch Image` and it will create the proper template. Also go to project General settings and select `Launch Images Source - Use Asset Catalog...`

Comment: Nice! Did you try that? Did you try that? Do I have to add the assets in a specific format and then can delete the LaunchScreen.storyboard? The Styleguides are not very clear about that

Comment: Yes... Open your Assets catalog (or create a new one), right-click in the assets section and select `App Icons & Launch Images -> New iOS Launch Image` and it will create the proper template. You can also find lots of utilities and scripts out there for auto-generating all the sizes.

Comment: Oh, and they can be jpegs or pngs.

Answer (score 2):

There is noway to accomplish what you want , you have to supply a storyboard file for the launch screen in plist , if you want to customize go to the layout and add image or anything you want , there is no place to configure a programmatically `UIView` for that

Comment: It is possible: see the confirmed answer

Comment: he describes how to set the resources , while your question aske for a uiview  programmatically ,  You updated the question it was **Is there a way to get rid of it and use a View or and UIImage instead?**

Comment: Exactly! I wanted to set it without the storyboard file and that was what I was looking for. I was probably not clear enough with my question so I changed it in order to help others with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Here a short description of the steps based on the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/6257435/donmag:

- create a new AssetSet: **+** ->  **AppIcons & Launch Images** -> **New iOS Launch Image**
- Go to your **Target Settings** to **General**
- Under **App Icons and Launch Images** clear the field Launch Screen File and select your LaunchScreen Asset set that you just created at **Launch Images Source**
- You might have to delete the App from the device/simulator that you test it on and the new Launch Image should show up on start