# View not covering full screen (programmatic storyboard Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

In Xcode 11 initial window is configured now in SceneDelegate, here my code and result on picture:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

     print("Scene willConnectTo.")
       guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    //  window =  UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
    window =  self.window ?? UIWindow()
     let mainView = ViewController()
    mainView.title = "TEST"
     let navigationController = UINavigationController()
    navigationController.viewControllers = [mainView]
    window?.backgroundColor = .red 
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to make view covering all screen ?

[image]

Comment: This code is working just fine in my simulator. No black lines on iPhone 8/11 Pro. What are your constraints for the view in ViewController? And can you tell me if replacing it with UIViewController() changes anything for you?

Comment: Don't have any constraints in VC, it's programmatic if replace with UIViewController it works but I need custom

Comment: I understand. I tried with a custom VC and it worked. Can you show your VC code? Especially code for the content that you are adding in self.view of your VC.

Comment: VC is empty, just blank template.

Comment: Can you add a view to it? And make it stretch to all 4 sides? Like let contentView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor)
        ])

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have a LaunchScreen storyboard.

Comment: This was my issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that its not possible to do LaunchScreen programmatically, as the screen will be loaded by the OS before the app launch itself, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32855727/1423345)